# Understanding semi-direct product construction

Tags: finite-groups, semidirect-product

I am a student studying semi-direct products for the first time, and have this question:say $G = N \rtimes H$, where $N$ is normal and $H$ is another subgroup that "acts" on $N$.  The quotient $G/N \cong H$. Would it be correct to say that if $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $N$ then $K/N > 1$ if and only if $K \cap H > 1$.  The way it seems to me is that if $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $N$ then the size of $K/N$ is a measure of the intersection of $K$ with $H$, if there's any "excess" elements of $K$ outside $N$ then they must cntain some from $H$.

Is this correct?

Thanks, Kerim

Comment: If k in K, then k = nh for some n in N, h in H. If k is not in N, then h is not the identity. However, K also contains h = n^-1 * k, since K contains N. Hence h is in the intersection of K with H and is not the identity.

Comment: OK, I think I got something like this when I tried to prove it in that direction, just wasn't sure my calculation was correct.  Just one more question, how is $K/N$ related to $K \cap H$, I mean $K$ here is not necessarily normal in $G$, so I can't use the group isomorphism theorem to work out the size of $K \cap H$.  But can we take $K \cap H$ to be $K/N$?

Comment: Every element of K is uniquely in the form nh with n in N and h in the intersection of K and H, so every element of K/N is uniquely of the form hN for h in the intersection of K and H. Thus K/N and the intersection of K and H are the same size with an explicit bijection.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple fact that holds for all subgroups $A$, $B$, and $C$. If $B \leq A$, then $A \cap BC = B(A \cap C)$.

So suppose that $G = NH$, where $N \cap H = 1$ and $N$ is a normal subgroup. Let $K$ be a subgroup such that $N \leq K$. Then by the  above result

$$K = K \cap NH = N(K \cap H)$$

Now applying an isomorphism theorem shows 
$$K / N \cong K \cap H / (N \cap (K \cap H)) = K \cap H / (N \cap H)$$

Since $N \cap H = 1$, it follows that $K/N \cong K \cap H$.

Does this answer your question?